# Any ideas of selecting multiple categories and subcategories with beautiful images?

Tags: multi-selection, categorization, aesthetics

Does anyone has any examples or ideas on making the following UX functional and aesthetically beautiful.

User has the option to select categories and subcategories on the onboarding process. Each subcategory has a nice visual image with a name on it.

Current solution I've created is the following. Each main category is a bubble (tag) with a text. Once the user selects a main category, the subcategories (with images) are displayed to the user. From there, the user can keep switching and choosing between main categories and subcategories selecting as many as they want.

My main issue with that is each category has 2-3 subcategories - so maximum 3 images - and the page seems kind of empty.

If you have any ideas or even examples it would be great. I'm browsing for select multiple categories inspiration but i can't find a lot of things. The screen is on mobile

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this how Clubhouse does this. Here the main categories are simply titles, but you could also apply an expandable accordion where you can simply select the whole category or expand it to select sub categories.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To answer the main issue that you pointed out, it depends on what you want to achieve by avoiding pages that seem empty. If it's only an eye candy concern then you can experiment with creative visual ways  like 3 bigger circles somewhere in the center, inclined horizonal stripes, there are a few ways that you can play with. Yet, if you want to consider possible subcategories additions in the future and need to design accordingly then having them in an quite empty list / grid shouldn't really bother the user.

[image]